# Need to parse a string to date without padded 0's

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdateformatter

I've read through a lot of examples, but the problem I'm facing is the date I'm getting doesn't have leading 0's and all the objective-c stuff I've found has them.  So I need to take the date:

4/9/2012 1:30 PM

And determine if it is today.  My place was to either grab today's date and compare it to the first part of that string, but as I said before I can't find anyway to make a date in objective c without leading 0's.  I'm hoping to avoid parsing that string manually to add leading 0's.

Comment: You tagged `NSDateFormatter`. What have you tried?

Comment: I looked through all the date format options and they all were marked as having leading 0's, so I didn't try any of them.  I'm hoping I only found the common one's and there's a format option without leading 0's.

Comment: I think a single M will give you the formatting that you want.  http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Comment: I'm going to try that Stefan H, I didn't see that page where it listed 1 or 2.

Comment: @Jhorra:  It says this: "Month - Use one or two for the numerical month, three for the abbreviation, or four for the full name, or five for the narrow name."  I would hope that means that a single 'M' will do the minimum necessary characters

Comment: I think you're right.  If you put that as an answer I'll mark it accepted.  None of the pages I found listed the single M as an option.

Comment: Leading zeroes are optional in date formatters (when parsing.)

Comment: You're saying [this document](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns) didn't give you the option of 1, 2, or 3 format characters??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that using the single M option for your date format string will allow it to parse a single digit month value:

The possible date formats are specified [here](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

Answer (score 2):

Use an NSDateFormatter object

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"h:mm a"];
```

if you want 0's

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
```

Answer (score 0):

@ynistersix answer is correct. In [Data Formatting Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html), they said that `NSDateFormatter` follows http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html

> h 1..2    11  Hour [1-12]. When used in skeleton data or in a skeleton
>   passed in an API for flexible date pattern generation, it should match
>   the 12-hour-cycle format preferred by the locale (h or K); it should
>   not match a 24-hour-cycle format (H or k). **Use hh for zero padding**.

This is consistent with most other languages. Like [.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

> "h" The hour, using a 12-hour clock from 1 to 12.

- 2009-06-15T01:45:30 -> 1
- 2009-06-15T13:45:30 -> 1

> "hh" The hour, using a 12-hour clock from 01 to 12.

- 2009-06-15T01:45:30 -> 01
- 2009-06-15T13:45:30 -> 01